# data.gov.in : limit parameter not working

Tags: url-parameters, data.gov

I am trying the following 
`https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json/?resource_id=e16c75b6-7ee6-4ade-8e1f-2cd3043ff4c9&api-key=APIKEY&limit=200`
I still get only 100 records. If I change the limit to 50 it gives me 50 records. How do I get the records from 101 - 200 and beyond?

I also tried using the *offset* parameter like so : 
    `&offset=50`
expecting it to give me record number 50-150, but it doesn't.

Does anyone have an Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this query](https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json/?resource_id=e16c75b6-7ee6-4ade-8e1f-2cd3043ff4c9&api-key=APIKEY) from OGD Platform.

you will find `total_records = 2947` and `count=100`.

Here, you have total of 2947 records and maximum of 100 records can be fetched in one query. If you want next 200 result, set `offset=2` which will give results from 201 to 300 and so on. You need to increase your offset by 1 in each query till *2947/100 = 29* (29th query will give 47 records) to get all data.

Parameter limit is used to fetch total number of records in each query and that will be between 0 to 100 (max). That's why when you set `limit=50`, you got 50 records but if you set `limit=110`, still you will get 100 records only.

Hope I my answer is clear enough. Good luck.